# How to fix Installation request for stripe/stripe-php ^6.37 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v6.37.0]. error

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use stripe in my laravel application and I'm failing to download the required files via composer. I'm getting the following error which is stopping everything from running:

> Installation request for stripe/stripe-php ^6.37 -> satisfiable by
>   stripe/stripe-php[v6.37.0].

How can I fix this error please help?

Comment: Check the requeriments for the package you are trying to install: https://packagist.org/packages/stripe/stripe-php probably on the full error message it is indicating the incompatibility. Could you post the full error please?

Comment: Oh i saw the error i have to enable curl in the php.ini file. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

for install last version use

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php:v6.37.0
```

```
composer require PACKEG:VERSION
```